# how to save uint8list to gallery as png

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a project that captures a screenshot of a widget and saves it in gallery.
my problem is there is few save to gallery packages in flutter and I tries almost all of them!
they save images as jpg which adds extra black bars around my widget which I don't want them to be there.
is there any package to save images to gallery in PNG format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution after 2 days of struggling with that.
you should save file as PNG to device path then use [image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver)
package to save it as file

```
 File('$dir/file_name${DateTime.now()}.png').writeAsBytes(pngBytes!);
 final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(imagePath);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the package doesn't return a filePath anymore despite their documentation stating it does...

Answer (score 2):

You can save image to gallery by using Image_gallery_saver plugin.[image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver)
. For the black bars , you have to make sure that the screenshot is attached to the widget , what you want it image.

```
await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(uint8list blob);
```